# Using database for forms django

Tags: django

I have an area where teachers can put homeworks for students.
Students can see these homeworks and when they click "send homework" button. they can fill a form so Teachers can see the homeworks from admin panel.
I have class to post homework.
I have 4 fields in class to post homework.

```
Fields = ["student number","Deadline","Lecture","Files"]
```

when students posting their homeworks, I want only use 2 `["student number","files"]` fields for the form and I want other fields `["deadline","Lecture"]` to be filled automatically from database.

What is the best way do it?

Comment: 5 fields? not 4?

Comment: The best way is to add deadline and lecture in the views.py. In your POST method you can add them. If you are having a problem in adding in POST function, you can add your views.py to understand

Comment: @BidhanMajhi, are you sure? We are talking about admin interface not a custom view.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting django [model clean method docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean):

> **Model.clean()** This method should be used to provide custom model validation, and to modify attributes on your model if desired. For instance, you could use it to automatically provide a value for a field, or to do validation that requires access to more than a single field.

For your scenario:

```
import datetime
from django.db import models

class Homeworks(models.Model):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        self.Deadline = datetime.date.today() + some delta time
        self.Lecture = ...
```

Also, remove this 'self-filled' fields from admin form interface:

```
class HomeworksAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ["student number","Files"]
```